# Magento 1 article stock in shopping cart - Group articles

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, stock

How do I check the stock of e.g. group articles?

Everything I have tried so far:

```
<p class="availability">
        <?php $gty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); ?>



   <?php 
   
     $thisProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
     if($thisProduct->isAvailable()):
        echo $this->__('In stock'); 
     else:
        echo $this->__('Out of stock');
     endif;
?>




        <?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>

getChildHtml('product_type_data_extra') ?> loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()?>

    </p>
```

ends in the output 0 - that means no stock is displayed although the stock is displayed correctly on the article detail page and there is a stock available... only in the shopping cart this does not work.